# What permissions are needed to delete a file in unix?

Tags: file, unix, permissions, delete-file, execute

I currently have a directory (udir), which has only read and write permissions for all users. This directory contains two files (file1 & file2)

I initially though that only write access was needed (on the directory) for me to be able to delete/remove a file via (rm udir/file1) but the rm command would give me access denied.  when i set the permissions to read, write, and execute, the rm command works.

Obviously the execute access is needed as well but why??

I thought the execute access on a directory was to be able to make it a working a directory and search its contents and access sub directories.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You actually need `read`, `write` and `execute` permissions on the directory, not on the file itself since the operation is done considering the permissions effects of directories.

A good documentation can be found on [this link](https://wpollock.com/AUnix1/FilePermissions.htm), which mentions the below in the section **Special Considerations on Directories**:

> To delete a file requires both write (to modify the directory itself)
> and execute (to stat() the file's inode) on a directory.  Note a user
> needs no permissions on a file nor be the file's owner to delete it!

Comment: Did you mean to write `read` and `execute` permissions?

Comment: Awesome document @nortontgueno

Comment: @silkfire this made me more confused as the link mentions both `write` and `execute`, but you ask if he meant `read` and `execute`...